# How do I create A javascript table in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo

I want to create a dynamic view  table with javascript in odoo, here is some of my code:

```
render_dashboards: function(){
            var model = "my.model";
            var domain = [];
            var fields = [];
            return this._rpc({
                model: model,
                method: 'get_data',
                args: [domain,fields],
            }).then(function (result) {
                let row = '';
                console.log({result})
                _.forEach(result, function (x) {
                    row += `<tr> 
                        <td></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>`
                });

                $("#sla-table > tbody").html(row)
            })
```

and here is method code:

```
@api.model
def get_data(self):
   return self.env["my.model"].search([])
```

however i get an error when i click on the menu:

```
TypeError: get_data() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

please, i appreciate any help/suggestions. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `get_data` with domain and fields arguments but the function takes only one argument. You can add them to `get_data` declaration or remove them from the `rpc` call.

The way you call `get_data` is similar to the [search_read](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/website_forum/static/src/js/website_forum.editor.js#L70-L73) function call, you can use it instead:

```
self._rpc({
    model: 'res.groups',
    method: 'search_read',
     args: [[], ['display_name']],
})
```

Comment: thank you so much, this works fine. any ideas you can give me on how i can also fetch some more columns from the table apart from the name?

Comment: The second argument (`fields`) is a list of field names to [read](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/838aae62fe3dae0d2877fa954b0c0886bfa4eb93/odoo/models.py#L5025), just append the field name to it

Comment: I can't  thank you Enough :). I really appreciate.